# OpenVPN:Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]

Tags: windows-8, openvpn

UPDATE: Solved. I forgot to install cert on my computer..sorry

My OpenVPN works well until I upgrade my Win 7 to 8. Now it can connect but not work properly.

Logs:

```
Tue May 07 15:35:59 2013 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
Tue May 07 15:36:00 2013 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=3 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
Tue May 07 15:36:00 2013 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
Tue May 07 15:36:01 2013 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=3 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
```

this repeats several times and followed:

```
Tue May 07 15:36:01 2013 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 172.16.254.1
Tue May 07 15:36:01 2013 Warning: route gateway is not reachable on any active network adapters: 172.16.254.1
Tue May 07 15:36:01 2013 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
Tue May 07 15:36:01 2013 Route addition fallback to route.exe
Tue May 07 15:36:01 2013 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
```

by several times.

I already run as admin account.

Windows 8 Pro, OpenVPN 2.3.1 ,TAP-driver is installed.

I guarantee my .ovpn is right.

Comment: This question should probably be removed, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just FORGOT to install the CERT KEY on my client..........

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether this would work for you: http://blogs.radicalsystems.com.au/lsilva/2012/08/08/openvpn-connect-and-windows-8